# declare CLLocationCoordinate2DMake data type variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, mapkit, segue

I have two screens, from screen A, I will pass some GPS coordinates to screen B. I have used some hard coded data to successfully draw route in screen B.

like this:

```
    func drawRoutes() {

        var points = [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.079980, 4.349850),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.079060, 4.350830),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.078210, 4.350490),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.077750, 4.350890),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.076760, 4.354600),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.075130, 4.351000),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.073800, 4.350690),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.071850, 4.352880),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.069320, 4.355940),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.069120, 4.356130),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.069120, 4.356130),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.069120, 4.356130),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.068570, 4.356950),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.067840, 4.358440),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.066730, 4.357490),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.066590, 4.358680),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.066580, 4.358680),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.066580, 4.358680),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.066830, 4.357490),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.067600, 4.358520),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.068650, 4.356920),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.074330, 4.350360),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.075520, 4.351880),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.076950, 4.355350),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.078000, 4.350690),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.078010, 4.350710),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.079520, 4.351560),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.080680, 4.350220),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.080760, 4.348890),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.079890, 4.349980),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.079890, 4.350000)]

        let polygon = MKPolyline(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)

        self.mapView.addOverlay(polygon)
        self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(polygon.boundingMapRect, animated: true)

        var startPoint = points[0]
        
        for i in 1...(points.count-1) {
            
            guard let request = createRequest(c1:startPoint, c2:points[i]) else { return }
            let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

            directions.calculate { [unowned self] (response, error) in
                guard let response = response else { return }
                let routes = response.routes
                let bestDest = routes[0]
                startPoint = points[i]
            }
        }
    }
```

but I couldn't figured out how to define a variable in screen B to take the value passed from Screen A using prepare for segue...

```
 var coodinatePoints: [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake]?
```

this doesn't really work, it says undeclared type CLLocationCoordinate2DMake...

Can I ask how to create a variable in Screen B to replace my hard coded coordinates, and take the coordinates I pass from screen A.

The coordinates data type looks like this:

```
 "coordinates": [
          {
            "lat": 0,
            "lng": 0,
            "time": "2020-10-31T10:37:01.757Z"
          }
        ]
```

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: You have a typo over there, you should be using `[CLLocationCoordinate2D]?`, not `[CLLocationCoordinate2DMake]?`

Answer (score 1):

The type is `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

Core Location dates from before Swift. In Objective C, structs cannot have initialisers like they can in Swift, so constructor functions are used.

`CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` is a function that constructs a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

You can declare your property as

```
var coodinatePoints: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]?
```

Comment: Thanks Paul，the error goes away, but I am still stuck to pass the right format of data. can you give me some hints what kind of data should I pass to the CLLocationCoordinate2D type ? thanks.

Comment: Your `points` array is an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.  You can simply assign `points` to `coordinatePoints`

Comment: thanks Paul, I figured out finally. Your answer didn't completely solve everything for me, but combine it with some other answers I got from stack overflow, I solved it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the complete solution for this: (also please check another question I asked in stack overflow here: [pass array of map coordinates to a draw a route on map in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622152/pass-array-of-map-coordinates-to-a-draw-a-route-on-map-in-swift/64622298#64622298)

So what do you do to pass some coordinates data from screen A (say you have a tableView) to screen B (you have the map).

So in screen A (viewControllerA):

You define the coordinates variable (according to your data model of course, should be an array usually)

```
var coordinates = [Coordinates]()
```

Then in your UITableViewDelegate extension, you append your coordinates into your coordinates array. Then use prepare segue to pass it to your destination viewController.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == Constants.segueTripListToTripMap {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? TripMapViewController,
                let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
                
                
                for i in 0...(tripList[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].coordinates.count-1) {
                    self.coordinates.append(tripList[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].coordinates[i])
                }
                
       
                
                destinationVC.coordinatePoints = coordinates
                coordinates = []
                
                 
            }
        } else {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? PolicyOverviewViewController,
                let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
                // do something
            }
        }

    }
```

In your screen B (where you map is). You define the variable to catch the data pass from screen A, which is `coordinatePoints`

```
var coordinatePoints: [Coordinates]?
```

then in your draw route function (or whatever name you call it). You convert this `coordinatePoints` into `CLLocationCoordinate2D` type like below:

```
    func drawRoutes() {

        var points:[CLLocationCoordinate2D] = coordinatePoints?.compactMap {
            guard let latitude = $0.lat, let longitude = $0.lng else { return nil }
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            } ?? [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.3676, 4.9041)]
                

        let polygon = MKPolyline(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)

        self.mapView.addOverlay(polygon)
        self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(polygon.boundingMapRect, animated: true)

        var startPoint = points[0]
        
        for i in 1...(points.count-1) {
            
            guard let request = createRequest(c1:startPoint, c2:points[i]) else { return }
            let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

            directions.calculate { [unowned self] (response, error) in
                guard let response = response else { return }
                let routes = response.routes
                let bestDest = routes[0]
                startPoint = points[i]
            }
        }
    }
```

there you go, when you click the table cell in screen A, it should pass the right coordinates into screen B and plot it on the map.

[image]